# How can I increase the effective focal length of my lenses?

Tags: canon

I have a Canon Zoom Lens EF 70-200mm 1:4 L IS USM mounted on Canon EOS 70D, how far can this lens zoom? If I wanted more zoom magnification to get as closer as possible to my subjects which is as far as 30 to 50 meters away (like birds, insects, small equipment tags of existing process vessels in oil refineries, etc), what would I need to do to achieve my purpose? What device do I need to add or use?

Comment: You need a longer lens.

Answer (score 4):

The one device that you could buy which would give you a greater focal length with your current lens is a [teleconverter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teleconverter) - Canon produce both a 1.4x version, which increases the focal length of your lenses by 1.4x, and a 2x version which doubles the focal length. However, note that both come with a drawback - they reduce the effective aperture of your lens, by 1 stop for the 1.4x version and 2 stops for the 2x version. 1 stop isn't a killer for an f/4 lens, but a 2 stop reduction will change your f/4 lens into an f/8 lens - and your body won't autofocus with an f/8 lens ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canon_Extender_EF#List_of_EOS_bodies_that_can_AF_at_f.2F8) has a list of the bodies which officially support autofocus at f/8, although some third party teleconverters can get round this limit with varying degrees of success).

However, a caveat: even with a teleconverter, you're not going to be able to get photos of insects at 30m (still too small), and getting good photos of birds depends a lot on which birds - ostriches will be easy, hummingbirds will be close to impossible. I have no idea how big equipment tags on oil refineries are, so can't help you there!

Other than that, as Michael has already commented, you need a longer lens.

Comment: Depending upon the amount of light/contrast, My 5DII will sometimes auto focus with f/8 combinations using a 3rd party teleconvertor.

Comment: Thanks - it turns out that there's a bunch of high-end bodies which can do f/8 autofocus as well so I've tweaked that bit of the answer.

Comment: I borrowed an 1.4 from my pusher (photo) for testing and noticed a reduction in image quality. A bit more "gritty" pixel structure. My setup Canon 550D, 70-300mm and 18-135mm.